# Android capture image and display

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have develop android application to capture the image and display. When I run the code code it opens the camera and and when it goes to display it gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException`

This is my code.

```
package com.www.dermatroid;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.ImageRecognitionPlugin;
import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.image.Image;
import org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.image.ImageFactory;
import org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

private final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;
private final int LOADING_DATA_DIALOG = 2;
private final int RECOGNIZING_IMAGE_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 

private TextView txtAnswer;
private LinearLayout screen;

private Bitmap bitmap;
private Image image;

private NeuralNetwork nnet;
private ImageRecognitionPlugin imageRecognition;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAnswer);
    screen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.screen);
    screen.setOnTouchListener(this);
    loadData();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 


            switch (requestCode) {
           case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {                     
                          Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                          txtAnswer.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, new BitmapDrawable(photo));                               
                }
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }          
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);       
    return false;
}

}
```

the log result

```
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.www.dermatroid/com.www.dermatroid.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.ImageRecognitionPlugin.setInput(ImageRecognitionPlugin.java:106)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at org.neuroph.contrib.imgrec.ImageRecognitionPlugin.recognizeImage(ImageRecognitionPlugin.java:176)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at com.www.dermatroid.Main.recognize(Main.java:140)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at com.www.dermatroid.Main.onActivityResult(Main.java:71)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
06-13 11:46:38.978: E/AndroidRuntime(3346):     ... 11 more
```

it gives error at `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`

Comment: what are the lines at line 140 and 71 in Main activity?

Comment: this only have total number of 82 lines. what do you mean by 140 ?\

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example activity that will launch the camera app and then retrieves the image and display it.

```
package com.demo.capture.image.camerademo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new 

Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            }
        });
    }

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }  
}
```

}

Note that the camera app, it gives you the ability to review/retake the image, and once an image is accepted, the activity displays it.

Here is the layout that the above activity uses. It is simply a LinearLayout containing a Button with id button1 and an ImageView with id imageview1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/photo"></Button>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And one final detail, be sure to add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
```

and if camera is optional to your app functionality. make sure to set require to false in the permission. like this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"></uses-feature>
```

to your manifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

See here how to achive this:

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Capture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
                  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);  
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
           Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
           imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);  
          }  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your probelm.

private String imgPath;

public Uri setImageUri() {
  // Store image in dcim
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new     Date().getTime() + ".png");
  Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
  return imgUri;
}

public String getImagePath() {
  return imgPath;
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
   try {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale = 1;
    while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
    scale *= 2;
        // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
     } catch (Throwable e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
  return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);       
    return false;
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
       switch (requestCode) {
       case CAMERA_REQUEST:
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {                     
           Bitmap photo = decodeFile(getImagePath);
           txtAnswer.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, new BitmapDrawable(photo));                               
       }
       break;
       default:
       break;
     }          
}
```